# bootstrap menu showing up blank/not able to style

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's the markup for the dropdown-menu div:

```
<div class="btn-group-two">
                <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Action
                <span class="caret white-caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul id="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li>one</li>
                  <li>two</li>
                  <li>three</li>
                </ul>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-group-two ul .dropdown-menu li a{
    color: red;
}
```

What is the problem? something I'm missing? thx.

Comment: That seems alright and fits the bootstrap documentation. What's the problem? Are you getting a JS error? Or nothing happens?

Comment: Menu opens white, when I use firebug it shows the items, but they are either white or invisible

Comment: Yup, I tried switching out the ul with a #menu id and that didn't work either.

Comment: Upload your problem to jsFiddle. Will be easier to find your problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6uC2y/6/ - here it is...

Comment: 1. There's no dropdown in this fiddle. 2. Notice that the CSS in your question addresses `anchor` elements, but the html does not contains anchors

Comment: 1.No dropdown? I included the js dropdown file, and it's properly linked in the html document. it worked for me. but you have to resize all the way to left to reveal the dropdown, fyi. 2. I took the anchors out of the css and it still wont change color, or even show up, but I know they are there. God this is HTML noobery, but thanks for helpin'

Comment: did you figure anything out? still have this problem.

Comment: Your fiddle is too crowded for me to understand anything. try and remove irrelevant code from there.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the bootstrap css and js files linked properly? http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

Removing the space between the ul and .dropdown-menu should work, your entire selector won't be recognized otherwise. 
try:

.btn-group-two ul.dropdown-menu li a {}

Comment: This still produces a menu that drops down, but the items show up as invisible or white.